# How to programmatically set the length of a function

Tags: javascript

The [`length` property of functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length) tells how long the 'expected' argument list is:

```
console.log((function () {}).length);  /* 0 */
console.log((function (a) {}).length); /* 1 */
console.log((function (a, b) {}).length); /* 2 etc. */
```

However, it is a readonly method:

```
f = function (a) {};
alert(f.length); // 1
f.length = 3;
alert(f.length); // 1
```

Is there a way to programmatically set that length? The closest I've come so far is to use the Function constructor:

```
f = new Function("a,b,c", "/* function body here */");
f.length; // 3
```

However, using Function is essentially the same as `eval` and we all know how bad that is. What other options do I have here?

Comment: Just interesting, what are the reasons that makes you even to think about this issue?

Comment: Why do you want to set the length? You know that when you actually call a function you can pass fewer than the "expected" arguments, or more? (If you pass more the function can access them via its `arguments` object.)

Comment: Out of interest, why do you want to do this?

Comment: I'm writing a mocking framework, and I'd like to make sure that I make as few modifications as possible to the functions which are being spied upon.

Comment: just write a small wrapper that expects n(3) number of arguments and calls the actual function with the real `arguments` passed.

Comment: @yi_H, yes, but what if there's 2 arguments, or 16? For now, I've used a dodgy copy-and-paste method which works for up to 10, but I was wondering if there was a better, programmatic method.

Comment: Another reason for wanting to do this is writing combinators for variadic functions. For example, it is easy to make a `reversed(f)` combinator to make a function that receives arguments in the reverse order but it is not trivial to make the returned function have the same length as the original.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For now, here's the best solution I could think of.

```
makeFunc = function (length, fn) {
    switch (length) {
    case 0 : return function () { return fn.apply(this, arguments); };
    case 1 : return function (a) { return fn.apply(this, arguments); };
    case 2 : return function (a,b) { return fn.apply(this, arguments); };
    case 3 : return function (a,b,c) { return fn.apply(this, arguments); };
    case 4 : return function (a,b,c,d) { return fn.apply(this, arguments); };
    case 5 : return function (a,b,c,d,e) { return fn.apply(this, arguments); };
    case 6 : return function (a,b,c,d,e,f) { return fn.apply(this, arguments); };
    case 7 : return function (a,b,c,d,e,f,g) { return fn.apply(this, arguments); };
    case 8 : return function (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h) { return fn.apply(this, arguments); };
    case 9 : return function (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i) { return fn.apply(this, arguments); };
    default : return function (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j) { return fn.apply(this, arguments); };
    }
};
```

Example usage:

```
var realFn = function () {
    return "blah";
};

lengthSix = makeFunc(6, realFn);

lengthSix.length; // 6
lengthSix(); // "blah"
```

Personally, I always cringe whenever I use copy and paste when programming, so I'd be very happy to hear of any better options.

**Update**

I thought of a method which could work for any arbitrary size, unlike the example above which is limited by how many times you want to copy-and-paste. Essentially, it dynamically creates a function (using `new Function`) which will return a function of the right size which then just proxies through to whatever function you pass to it. Yeah that does hurt your head. Anyway, I thought I'd benchmark it against the above...

http://jsperf.com/functions-with-custom-length (you can see the 'evil' code there too).

The evil method is many hundreds of times slower than the hacky copypasta method, so there you go.

Comment: This is one of the reasons we need macros in JavaScript.

Answer (score 12):

It turns out the `length` property on functions is [configurable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length), which means you can use [`.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) to change the value of length on a function.  Example:

```
function hi() {}
hi.length === 0; // Expected

Object.defineProperty(hi, "length", { value: 5 })
hi.length === 5; // Intriguing
```

This works in the latest version of Chrome and Firefox, but it does not work in Safari (v9.1.1).

Comment: This also works in modern V8 (I tested with Node 6.x).  Thanks!

Comment: Works on Node v8.15.0 as well! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I am doing something like what you're asking for using roughly the following:

```
/* Make a new function with a given size */
function SizedFunc(num_args) {
  if(SizedFunc.sizedFuncs === undefined) SizedFunc.sizedFuncs = {};
  if(SizedFunc.sizedFuncs[num_args] === undefined) {
    var argNames = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < num_args; ++i) {
      argNames.push('arg' + i);
    }
    SizedFunc.sizedFuncs[num_args] = new Function(argNames, 'return this.apply(null, arguments);');
  }
  return SizedFunc.sizedFuncs[num_args];
}
```

This *does* use a Function constructor but in a strictly limited way and only ever once per function size to create a function wrapper (which is cached for that size) after that I use wrapper.bind(real_function) to provide the implementation as a function expression/object.

Advantages are that any size is supported and we aren't hard coding the function definitions but actual function implementations are never done in an 'eval' like way and the string passed to the Function constructor is always the same.

```
/* ---- example ---- */ 
var a = SizedFunc(4).bind(function() { console.log.apply(null, arguments); });
var b = SizedFunc(4).bind(function(a, b, c, d) { console.log(a + b, c + d); });

console.log(typeof a);  // -> function
console.log(typeof b);  // -> function
console.log(a.length);  // -> 4
console.log(b.length);  // -> 4
a(1, 2, 3, 4)           // -> 1 2 3 4
a(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);       // -> 1 2 3 4 5
b(1, 2, 3, 4)           // -> 3 7
```

I'm sure there are plenty of reasons this is bad, too (starting with the use of bind meaning functions created this way can't be bound to an object) but it is useful in situations where one needs to be able to create a function of arbitrary length dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [ECMA Script standard, revision 5.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) on page 103, the `.length` parameter on a `Function` object is not writable so it is set when the function is declared and not changable (if implemented per spec).

Thus, the only way to create a function with a particular `.length` upon demand is to either have a bunch of functions lying around of various length (as nickf suggests), create a Function object (as you've already mentioned) or use `eval()` with a dynamically created string.  I don't know what problem yu're actually trying to solve, but I personally find nothing wrong with using eval() if you know the source of the code you're using it with and have a way of either checking it or knowing what it will or won't have in it.  In this case, programmatically generating a certain number of parameters in a string before calling eval() on it poses no security risk I'm aware of.

If this is all your own code, you can just create a new property on the function `.dynLength` that is mutable and set it to whatever you want and have your code use that.

Comment: Thanks for that, however the *real* problem with using `Function` or `eval` is the scope in which that is executed. It's not equivalent to writing that code in the current scope, which doesn't work in my case.

Comment: @nickf - what's the real problem you're trying to solve?  Why do you dynamically need to create a function with a particular `.length` value?

Comment: it's a library which wraps arbitrary functions to do things such as stubbing & spying (eg: counting the number of calls, storing the arguments, etc). Since code which uses it *may* be checking the length property of the function, I'd like to make sure it stays the same after being wrapped.

Answer (score 1):

There’s an *npm* module **[util-arity](https://www.npmjs.com/package/util-arity)** which does what you want:

```
const arity = require('util-arity');

arity(3, () => {}).length;  //» 3
```